# Eclipse Photon excessive garbage collection

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, garbage-collection, g1gc

I'm using the latest Eclipse Photon Java EE IDE with Java 8 "1.8.0_181" 64-Bit on Windows 10.

After about an hour of usage, it becomes so unresponsive, that it's effectively unsuable. I checked the eclipse.ini and the default memory settings `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m` which I changed to 512m and 2g respectively. The current GC settings are:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
```

Here is a Visual GC memory profile. The long linear growth in Eden space was while I did nothing but look at the graph. The spikes are during actual work.

[image: Visual GC Memory profile]

GC of Eden space is basically triggered whenever it reaches ~512m. After an hour, every other keystroke seems to trigger GC, but the max heap size isn't even close to being exhausted.

Are there any GC settings to tune this? How can I find out what triggered the GC anyway?
(Or is this an Eclipse bug?)

Comment: What should an answer contain for this? There's no question here.

Comment: I've updated the question. The question is why Eclipse becomes unresponsive. My preliminary diagnosis is, that it's bc. the GC is triggered so often. Now I'm not sure whether I'm interpreting the data right and if yes, whether there are some GC settings to mitigate this. Or maybe its a bug in Eclipse, G1GC, JVM...